# How to make keylistener in Edit text in android?

Tags: android

I have a Edit text named as password when I enter value and press done it clear focus from password edit text and when I press device back then it not lossing focus from password edit text.

**Code**

```
m_InputPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT|| event.getAction()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                m_InputPassword.clearFocus();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your question, the problem is your field is losing focus when you clicking on back button?

Comment: I want when I enter values in password Edit text and after completed press device back then it will hide soft keyboard then I want password Edit text to clear focus

Answer (score 0):

Write below onBackPressed in activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!m_InputPassword.hasFocus()){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it fragment or activity?

Comment: activity I already define onbACKpRESS for going back from activity

Comment: here is code   /*This is new changes, This method functional on device back pressed*/
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

  if ((currentTime - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
   // Double Press
   moveTaskToBack(true);
  } else {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   lastPressTime = currentTime;
  }
 }

Comment: I had not wriiten dont understand where to write

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after research of this I came to this solution, let me know if it's worked for you.
first of all you will need to implement a custom EditText
and add this view in your xml

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText implements OnClickListener{

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
setOnClickListener(this);
}

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOnClickListener(this);
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

          setFocusable(false);
          hideKeyBoard();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}

private void hideKeyBoard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    v.setFocusable(true);
    showKeyBoard();
}

private void showKeyBoard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
}
```

}

xml

```
 <com.example.listissue.MyEditText 
    android:id="@+id/test_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="1234"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```